# How to develop a small linux distro?

Tags: linux, compiling, busybox

Since Linux uses open-source packages, I was wondering if I could develop my own Linux distro by compiling these packages.

I tried to read the Linux From Scratch book but it's quite big and uses lots of packages.

I want to develop a small Linux distro using the Linux kernel and busybox. I tried searching on the internet but didn't find a good guide.

Comment: Linux is very flexible. That is the reason by you need many packages to achieve a certain goal. What do you want to learn by developing a distribution on your own?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Mike Chirico has [a document](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/cdrom.htm) on this.  There's an [IBM developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-embedded-distro/section3.html) that seems relevant, too.  Good luck, you'll have fun with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be brutally honest here: at this point you do no one, yourself included, any favors by creating your own fully-customized distro. Several existing distros have established mechanisms for creating customized versions; I recommend you start with one of them and add/modify specific packages as appropriate.

Comment: I have to disagree. LFS, and to a lesser extent, Gentoo, exist so that you can learn how to make a distro. I seriously doubt anyone would put LFS into an enterprise production environment, but I also heard a rumor that Arch linux started as a LFS instance.

Comment: @Bruce: Learning *how* to make your own distro is well and good, but I still stand by my answer. As for Arch Linux, whether or not it started out as LFS is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't just want to have custom distro. I want to learn things

Comment: -1: The question is not "do you think I should make my own distro?" but "how to develop a distro?".